# AutoMapper will not map when hiding inherited member

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a mapping to a class that has an inner mapping that hides a member from the class it inherited from. Everything gets mapped properly except for the hidden member. This is from a .NET Standard 2.0 library. Interestingly, if I use the latest AutoMapper (10.0.0) compiled for .NET 4.6.1 this works correctly. I am interested in the disparity between the two, but I'd like to know if there is a way to get it to work with the .NET Standard library.

Running the following in LINQPad 6 will have the issue, while running it in LINQPad 5 will not (it uses the .NET 4.6.1 version).

```
void Main() {
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<SubObject, ExtendedSubObject>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Comment, o => o.Ignore());
        cfg.CreateMap<MainObject, ExtendedMainObject>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Age, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.Missing, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Missing));
    });
    
    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var source = new MainObject {
        Id = 7,
        Name = "George",
        Missing = new SubObject {
            Value = "No, I'm here! You did it!"
        }
    };
    
    var destination = mapper.Map<ExtendedMainObject>(source);
    destination.Dump();    
}

public class MainObject {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public SubObject Missing {get;set;}
}

public class SubObject {
    public string Value {get;set;}
}

public class ExtendedMainObject : MainObject {
    public string Age {get;set;}
    public new ExtendedSubObject Missing {get;set;}
}

public class ExtendedSubObject : SubObject {
    public string Comment {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I'd fix the model if I were you :) It's terrible and adding AM in the mix only makes it more confusing. That being said, check `destination.Missing.Dump()` instead.

Comment: You're correct, it is in `destination.Missing.Dump()` which only serves to confuse me further. The actual implementation is more complex and is covered by a test, which always has the mapped inner object as null. Agree that the model is bad though. I'll keep digging, and thank you.